# Creating 2 dimensional list matrix

Tags: list, haskell, dimensional

How do you create a list-based matrix of `1`'s with given row and column counts?  For example, like:

```
row=3,column=4 -> [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `replicate`:

```
onesMatrix rows cols = replicate rows (replicate cols 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative method using list comprehension. Let's have a look at the basics:

```
Prelude> [ 2*x | x <- [1..4] ]
[2,4,6,8]
```

So that gives you one number for each element in the list `[1..4]`. Why not, instead of doubling `x`, just have a `1`:

```
Prelude> [ 1 | x <- [1..4] ]
[1,1,1,1]
```

And if we want three of them, we can pull the same trick:

```
Prelude> [ [1|x<-[1..4]] | x<-[1..3] ]
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Thus we can define

```
twoDlist r c = [ [1|x<-[1..c]] | x<-[1..r] ]
```

which gives

```
Prelude> twoDlist 3 4
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor 

matrix r c = [1] <* [1..c] <$ [1..r]
```